# Undo the Removal of an Interesting Tag

Tags: feature-request, tag-watching

It has happened to me twice that I have accidently removed one of my interesting tags by clicking the cross next to the interesting tag on the main page. This is rather annoying because it happens easily -- you just have to miss the tag and click the cross a few pixels to the right of the tag. In addition, if you accidently remove a tag and then add it again, it will be added to the *bottom* of the list of interesting tags, and not at its previous position. This is bad, because the human brain (I think) is good at remembering *where* an object is. Once I happened to delete the Delphi tag (which was the first of my interesting tags), and it took weeks before I got used to look at the end of the list instead.

Hence it would be good if

- the cross was removed, if
- there was a confirmation "Do you want to remove this tag?", if
- there was a possibility to undo the removal of a tag, or if
- you could change the order of the interesting tag items.

The problem of accidentally removing a tag from favorites gets more annoying for short tags, such as `C`. The cross button occupies about a half of the clickable area, so I very often accidentally remove the tag instead of filtering the question.

It would be very nice to have a deletion confirmation or an undo feature.

Comment: Drag and drop ordering should be quite easy to implement, especially with help from jQuery (which SE already uses).

Comment: +1 for "such as `c`". I've deleted it *more* than twice.

Comment: I agree tiny tiny tags are a pain to click as you can accidentally click the cross. I dont have very good fine motor skills as it is :)

Answer (score 4):

There's also a script on StackApps that removes the <kbd>X</kbd>-buttons from the tags altogether: [Stackapps: Remove Delete-Favourite-Tag-Buttons Script](https://stackapps.com/questions/2540/remove-delete-favourite-tag-buttons-script)

I dug a bit further: There are quite some interesting scripts to handle tags at StackApps:

- [Stack Overflow Tag Manager](https://stackapps.com/questions/2062/stack-overflow-tag-manager)
- [Collapse interesting and ignored tags sections!](https://stackapps.com/questions/2470/collapse-interesting-and-ignored-tags-sections)
- [Unhide the Ignored Tags Hider](https://stackapps.com/questions/2372/unhide-the-ignored-tags-hider)
- [Hide tag info popup](https://stackapps.com/questions/2129/hide-tag-info-popup)
- [Color Tags Script](https://stackapps.com/questions/3230/color-tags-script)
- [Favourite Tags Numerical Keyboard Shortcuts Script](https://stackapps.com/questions/2543/favourite-tags-numerical-keyboard-shortcuts-script)
- [Fitts's Law Favourite Tags Script](https://stackapps.com/questions/2541/fittss-law-favourite-tags-script)

As I see none of these apps actually lets you sort the tags, some improvement seems in the overall tag handling seems to be possible however.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple guide to reordering your tags:

- Write down all your interesting tags in the order you want them to show up
- Remove all your tags
- Add them in the order you would like them.

Once you've done this enough times because you've accidentally clicked remove, you'll get smart and write a greasemonkey script that disables the remove button. :)