# How to draw attention to an old unanswered question on meta?

Tags: discussion, questions, meta, bump

I encountered exactly the same problem as described in this question on Meta: [Undo the Removal of an Interesting Tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66449/undo-the-removal-of-an-interesting-tag). That question was asked in 2010 and got almost no response.

How could I draw an attention to that problem? I think, asking the same question once again is not a proper way.

Answer (score 5):

The same way as you draw attention to questions on the main site:

1. Edit. Are you sure there's **nothing** you can edit? Isn't there *any* new information you could add which would enhance the request? Adding new supporting information to a feature request may be what it needs to be implemented. It doesn't have to be the question you edit. You can edit an answer too.
2. Post a bounty. You need at least 75 reputation to post a bounty.
3. Answer. Do you have a new or improved solution you could offer?

Comment: Neither would work. 1. There's nothing to edit, I have exactly the same problem. 2. I don't have enough rep on meta for opening a bounty. 3. How can I answer if it is a feature request?

Comment: @Andrey - these are the only ways you can do it. Are you sure there's **nothing** you can edit? Isn't there *any* new information you could add which would enhance the request? With 145 points you should have enough reputation to start a bounty.

Comment: Thank you, I thought 145 was not enough.

Comment: I always see you add your answer as CW. Any reason?

Comment: @hims056 - I have more than enough reputation on MSO to last me a lifetime.

Comment: @Andrey for what it's worth, I also see features I like many times and despite my best efforts and my [best shiny reputation](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/152859/sha-wiz-dow-ard?tab=bounties&sort=offered) they get no attention. Just keep in mind that only few of the suggestions will get real attention and even fewer will be [implemented](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/152419/make-it-clear-the-op-has-the-final-vote-on-suggested-edits).